# angular the same element with different bindings on different screen sizes

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using the tooltip from `ng-bootstrap`. So basically on different screen sizes, I need the tooltip to show up in different positions:

```html
    <span class="my-tooltip-lg" [placement]="'bottom'" #myTooltip="ngbTooltip"></span>
    <span class="my-tooltip-sm" [placement]="'left'" #myTooltip="ngbTooltip"></span>
```

```css
    @media (max-width: 575px) {
        .my-tooltip-lg {
            display: none;
        }

        .my-tooltip-sm {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 576px) {
        .my-tooltip-lg {
            display: block;
        }

        .my-tooltip-sm {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

So what I am trying to achieve is that on different screen sizes, there is only one visible `span` ready for tooltip. But the problem with this is I got the below error:

```
Template parse errors: Reference "#myTooltip" is defined several times
```

So I am wondering what else I can do?

Comment: you can not have same id for different elements in template, `#`

Comment: @Plochie Yes. But the problem is what I can do to achieve what I want?

Comment: Is it like for large screen tooltip should  lets say be on top, and for smaller screen tooptip should at bottom?

Comment: @Plochie On large screens, the tooltip should be at the bottom. On small screens it should be on the left as it may stretch out of the viewport.

Comment: Are you doing operation with `#myTooltip` ?

Comment: Do you have a Sample StackBlitz to work with? If not, would it be possible to create one and share it across?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need media observer here, use `@angular/flex-layout`, this will provide you event when there is change in screen size.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5zhvj?file=app%2Ftooltip-basic.ts) (To view the changes click on open in new window and check by resizing the window)

```html
<div style="padding-left: 200px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent" [placement]="tooltipPosition">
  Some Button
</button>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { MediaObserver } from "@angular/flex-layout";

@Component({
  selector: "ngbd-tooltip-basic",
  templateUrl: "./tooltip-basic.html"
})
export class NgbdTooltipBasic {
  tooltipPosition = "top";

  constructor(private readonly mediaObserver: MediaObserver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mediaObserver.media$.subscribe(x => {

      if (x.mqAlias === 'sm') {
        this.tooltipPosition = 'left';
      }
      else {
        this.tooltipPosition = 'bottom';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code but my intention is to show different layouts on mobiles and desktops so i guess there is no screen size change here.

Comment: Actually I answered according to ur question. If u want to show different layouts, you can use same methodology. U can update the question accordingly so that I can update the answer here.

Comment: Not a prob! I think I figured it out myself. Thanks for your help! I am making your answer the correct one!